# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne references an unknown entity for entities from different applications and databases in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using Springboot for an app that uses some classes that are managed in another application and stored in another database. My `Flight` class, which is managed in the current application in a local database, has an attribute of type `Aircraft`, which is also defined in the current application but is managed in the other application and stored in another database.

The `Flight` class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "app1")
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "flight_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "flight_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String callsign;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="aircraft_id", nullable=false)
    private Aircraft aircraft;
    private Date date;
    private Operator operator;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
}
```

My `Aircraft` class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(schema = "app2")
public class Aircraft implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "aircraft_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "aircraft_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="operator_id", nullable=false)
    private Operator operator;
    private String registration;
    private String acType;
}
```

I wrote a Jpa query in a `FlightRepository` which uses as a parameter the `registration` attribute from the `Aircraft` attribute of the `Flight` class:

```java
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {
    Flight findFirstByDestinationAndAircraftRegistrationOrderByDateDesc(String destination, String registration);
}
```

but this results in the following exception:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.student.application.domain.app1.Flight.aircraft references an unknown entity: com.student.application.domain.app2.Aircraft
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 86 more
```

If I add a `@OneToMany` annotation to the `Aircraft` class the problem remains the same. If I remove both the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations, I get a `Cannot join to attribute of basic type` exception.

These are the configuration classes for the two databases:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.student.application.repository.app1",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "app1EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "app1TransactionManager")
public class App1DBConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource app1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean app1EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(app1DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.student.application.domain.app1");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager app1TransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                app1EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.student.application.repository.app2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "app2EntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "app2TransactionManager")
public class App2DBConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.app2")
    public DataSource app2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean app2EntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(app2DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.student.application.domain.app2");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager app2TransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                app2EntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 entitymanagers each managing different entities. Unless they are in 1 entitymanager you cannot use those.

Comment: In this case, what would be the correct approach in order to be able to connect to 2 different databases and also be able to use the `registration` of an `Aircraft` in queries? I've thought of storing the `registration` in the `Flight` as a separate field, but that wouldn't be very elegant I believe

Comment: afaik you cannot. They are seperate database so they cannot see the data from one another.

Comment: Then is there any other way of writing that query using the `registration` from the `Aircraft`, without adding a duplicate in the `Flight` class

Comment: No there isn't. You have seperate databases so either duplicate the data or make the data accessible from 1 to another database.

Comment: Is there a recommended method for doing that? I followed this tutorial for connecting to 2 different databases: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

Comment: That depends on your database and the options it provides. I wonder why they are 2 different database in the first place (are they really 2 different database or just 2 different schemas in the same database, or are they accidentilly just 2 database?).

Comment: They are 2 different applications. One manages `Aircraft` and `Operator`s and the other one manages flight plans and `Flight`s with a different purpose, but it also requires data on `Aircraft` and `Operators`. The databases are stored in different locations

Comment: Then your only options is to duplicate the data or at least link based on the PK and only store that.

Answer (score 0):

One flight can have just one Aircraft but one aircraft can have more than one flight... so on aircraft you should have
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Flight")` Join column is not needed here

Im assuming you want it to be mapped by flight and have all the info stored in flight table. you could allso join tables and make flight_aircraft table.

annotations On Flight ->
`@ManyToOne`
`@JoinColumn(name="aircraft_id")`